# Tap events for AlertIOS are passed to parent component below dialog (React-native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Upgraded our React-native project to `0.20` and all of our AlertIOS dialogs are now broken. What's happening is the tap event is being passed below to the component, and the buttons on the AlertIOS are never touched.

Here's a simplified example and screenshot:

```
class TabOption extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  resetData = () => {
    AlertIOS.alert('Reset Data',
      'Are you sure you want to reset your data?',
      [{text:'Yes', onPress: () => console.log('FIRE')},
       {text:'No'}])
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection: 'column',backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.resetData} style={styles.tabOptionContainer}>
          <Text> Disconnect </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabOptionContainer: {
    width:Dimensions.width,
    height:50,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor:'white',
  }
});
```

In the screenshot below, if I click either `Yes` or `No` the tap event is passed to the component beneath the alert. I can actually fully interact with the component, while no tap events are fired on the alert itself.

[image: Alert fail]

Note: it was a rather large upgrade. We bumped React from `0.14` to `0.20`. Before the upgrade, everything was working just fine. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue, tapping on yes or no doesn't dismiss the alert box but instead is tapping the component beneath.

I used your example and tweaked it a little bit [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/_MicHw).

The taps on the alert boxes work fine. Check it out.

**Code**

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AlertIOS,
  AppRegistry,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Component,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

class StackOverflowApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      color: 'pink'
    };
  }

  resetData = () => {
    AlertIOS.alert('Reset Data',
      'Are you sure you want to reset your data?',
      [{text:'Yes', onPress: () => this.setState({color: 'red'})},
       {text:'No', onPress: () => this.setState({color: 'blue'})}])
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection: 'column',backgroundColor: this.state.color}}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.resetData} style={styles.tabOptionContainer}>
          <Text> Disconnect </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabOptionContainer: {
    width:Dimensions.width,
    height:50,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor:'white',
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('StackOverflowApp', () => StackOverflowApp);
```

Comment: Hey @GHamaide I appreciate you taking the time to respond but I'm very confused on how this addresses the question? I know you have a working component, and in our case it usually works too, so can you explain how this would solve the touch event problem for us?

Comment: My point is mostly to tell you that the error doesn't come from the code you gave us but from something else. The reproduction of your code works as supposed to.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'm not sure that would qualify as an "answer" in the sense it creates a solution to the original problem. However, I will indeed post a solution here when I have found one (so far we've just been rebuilding the app).

Comment: OK, I'll leave it for the comments, but I agree, it should have been a comment. My bad.